# How to edit Cura profile in Octoprint?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, octoprint

In Cura, I can edit my .ini profile settings as needed, for example, when I change filament or models. It's annoying to have to edit the profile on another computer and update it on my Pi just to change the infill, etc. I've searched http://plugins.octoprint.org/ and can't find any plugins that do this.

Comment: I noticed that your question has not had much activity lately, are you still looking for an answer to this question? How might we be able to close some gaps?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, this is currently not possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is an import function.
https://github.com/foosel/OctoPrint/wiki/Plugin:-Cura

Btw. now in Cura 2.1 you'll also need to reimport your .ini.

Regards :)

Answer (score 2):

You can manually edit the .profile by using an SSH terminal program (e.g putty) to log into your Pi

Then cd ./octoprint/slicingProfiles

ls to see folders (on mine I see cura)
cd cura 
ls to see profile files e.g fred.profile
sudo nano fred.profile

move down to where you can see the slicing parameters and edit away

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which asks for a way to edit the profiles *within octoprint*. Editing them through SSH (from another computer) is exactly what the question seeks to avoid.

Comment: IDK, this seems like a pretty decent answer given you most likely access octoprint from a browser on another computer, so to putty in, is only another window, no editing of files and then having to FTP them over. Just edit in place.